# Что такое localIdentifier видео и как его получить?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

Мне нужно получить localIdentifier видео, которое сохраняется в библиотеке Photos, чтобы получить его phasset с помощью этой функции: `fetchAssets (withLocalIdentifiers:options:)`. Я не очень понимаю, что такое localIdentifier и как его получить. Это URL видео? Если да, то как мне его получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из [документации](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phobject/1622400-localidentifier?language=objc)

> localIdentifier
>
> A unique string that persistently identifies the object.

То есть это постоянный уникальный идентификатор ресурса. Выглядит он например как `031E8A62-0C6F-4CCC-AD7C-3142A15787AB/L0/001`

Получить идентификаторы для последующего использования можно так

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)

for i in 0...fetchResult.count - 1 {
    NSLog("%@", fetchResult[i].localIdentifier)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь...ваш ответ правильный!